# How to get expiry year in YYYY format from STPPaymentCardTextField

Tags: ios, swift, date, stripe-payments

I'm integrating [Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios) payment gateway and I've used `STPPaymentCardTextField` to get the card details. I need to send the expiry year in `YYYY` format to my server. By I get the year(expirationYear) in `YY` format. How can I get the date in `YYYY` format?

Comment: Can it be anything else than 20xx?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I guess it wont be anything else than 20xx. Is it ok to concatenate string "20"?

Answer (score 2):

First XX skipped by obvious reasons - they are 20. So you can do

```
let expirationYearFull = "20" + expirationYear
```

in Swift.

One thing that you should definitely be worried of is, why do you ever send card data to your server? You should make Stripe tokenization and never send card data to your server. Make sure you've read SDK ref, guides, use https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPToken.html and make sure you won't be violating [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/)

Comment: Already I'm using this. I thought there will be any other solution

Comment: Once again, make sure you are not violating PCI DSS by sending credit card data to your server